# Using curl to upload to dropbox file request link

Tags: curl, dropbox

I've seen some questions related to this topic but I can't find something specific.
I would like to know if it is possible to upload a file using curl through a [dropobox file request link](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/create-file-request), without any token or authentication, since to send files by file request it is not necessary to have a dropbox account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox unfortunately doesn't offer a way to programmatically upload to file requests like this, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to programmatically upload a file without going through the big ol pain in ass use of the DB API. With the short term tokens transition, even a simple API upload implementation is complex. Doing it via a file request would be great, since the URL is public anyway and accepts any arbitrary file in the browser.